# How to pass list of arguments in CSV to a Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, csv, plpgsql, rds

I've written a Postgres function which involves inserting records in tables. It takes a few arguments as input.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add_person(
    name character varying,
    email character varying,
    level integer,
    company_id integer,
    comp_list integer[])
```

I have a CSV which has columns that match the input arguments of the function. How do I feed the CSV as list of input and call the function?

**EDIT**
The database lives in RDS instance of AWS. So I don't have `superuser` permission to copy the file to a temp table. `file_fdw` is also not an option since this extension is not supported by Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`COPY` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) you need a table to import data from a CSV file. Use a temporary table to buffer the data from a file, e.g.:

```
do $$
begin
    create temp table temp (
        name character varying, 
        email character varying, 
        level integer, 
        company_id integer, 
        comp_list integer[]);
    copy temp from 'c:\data\test.csv' (format csv, header);
    perform add_person(name, email, level, company_id, comp_list)
    from temp;
    drop table temp;
end
$$;
```

Alternatively, you can use the extension [`file_fdw,`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) example:

```
create extension if not exists file_fdw;

create server csv_server foreign data wrapper file_fdw;

create foreign table csv_file (
    name character varying, 
    email character varying, 
    level integer, 
    company_id integer, 
    comp_list integer[]
) server csv_server
options (filename 'c:\data\test.csv', format 'csv', header 'on');

select add_person(name, email, level, company_id, comp_list)
from csv_file;
```

Comment: I followed your first method to create a function callled `add_persons_from_csv` with path of the file as the sole argument. And I used `$1` in the `copy` command: `copy temp from $1 (format csv, header);` However I got syntax error around `$1`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You cannot use the parameter directly in `COPY`. You should use `execute` ([a dynamic command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)) for this.

Comment: I have this line in my original function `insert into person (name, email, level, company_id, comp_list) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`. And it works fine without `execute`

Comment: Even if I hardcode the filepath inside the function, it complains `ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file. ` Thing is I don't have superuser priviledge.

Comment: `file_fdw` is not supported by Amazon RDS, so can't use your second method either.

Comment: All these information should be included in the question. It's obvious that `COPY` needs superuser privileges. You are left with writing this functionality in your client app.